# Key Binding: /usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --s

Tags: 13.10, shutdown

I just upgraded from 13.4 to 13.10 & my custom key binding for shutdown or restart doesn't work.

It seems that

```
/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper
```

Doesn't exist.

Any ideas or alternatives?

Thanks
Barry